# How to align a link_to in loop 1 of 2 to the bottom of the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I currently have two logic loops in index.html.erb.

Loop one handles logic for specific Reviews. I want to add a `link_to` in this loop as part of the `if` logic but I want it placed at the bottom of the page.

I am assuming a container and a text-align is what I should implement.  This is my code:

[image: Review Page]

```rb
<% if @tea %>
    <h1> Reviews for <%= @tea.flavor%> - <%= @tea.brand_name%></h1>
      <%= link_to "Add a Review", new_tea_review_path%> 
<% else %>
    <h1> All the Reviews </h1>
<% end %>



<ul>
<% @reviews.each do |review| %>


  <li>
    <%= review.tea.flavor%> : <%= link_to review.title, review_path(review)%> - <%= review.rating%>
  </li>  <br>


<% end %>

</ul>
```

Comment: Could you use interpunction in your sentences to make it easier for readers to help you?

Comment: Please just add an example of the desired HTML output to the question.

Comment: I've cleaned it up and added a picture of the link I would like to format and adjust.